# Sending backslash via AJAX to C# WebMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, .net-4.0

I have following simple code which sends a few parameters to a C# Webmethod. Webmethod tests for database connection and returns Success or error Message

**TestDb.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestDb.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestDb" %>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#BtnTestDb").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "TestDb.aspx/CheckDbConnection",
                    data: '{"ServerName":"' + $("#edtDbServer").val() +
                        '", "UserName":"' + $("#edtDbUser").val() +
                        '", "Password":"' + $("#edtDbPassword").val() +
                        '", "Database":"' + $("#edtDbName").val() + '"}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("success: " + response.d)
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert("error:" + error);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="4">
        <tr>
            <td class="">Server</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="edtDbServer" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="edtDbUser" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="edtDbPassword" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Database</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="edtDbName" /></td>
            <td align="left"><input type="button" id="BtnTestDb" value="Test Connection" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**TestDb.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Services;

public class TestDb: System.Web.UI.Page {

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static string CheckDbConnection(string ServerName, string UserName, string Password, string Database) {
        if (ServerName != "" && UserName != "" && Password != "" && Database != "") {

            SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            builder.DataSource = ServerName;
            builder.UserID = UserName;
            builder.Password = Password;
            builder["Initial Catalog"] = Database;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
            try {
                conn.Open();
                conn.Close();
                return "Ok";
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return "Error: " + ex.Message;
            }
        } else {
            return "Error: Required fields are missing.";
        }
    }
}
```

This code works properly as long as database is default instance (no backslashes in name)
However if I have a database instance such as `.\sqlexpress` this code breaks.

**Problem:**

By adding backslash in servername input, Webmethod will not accept the input and gives me `Internal server error` message.

However by adding two backslashes (`.\\sqlexpress`) webMethod will receive the data but now I have two backslashes on service side (exactly `.\\sqlexpress`)

**Question:**

How can I send single backslash to `WebMethod` specifically `.\sqlexpress`

**Notes:**

I know it is possible to replace all backslashes in client side to two backslashes and replace them back to single backslash in server side. I am preferably looking for a better solution.

Comment: Wait, are you saying that .\\sqlexpress doesn't work on server-side? If .\\sqlexpress is in a string on the server-side, it should escape to .\sqlexpress anyway. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Try `builder.DataSource = @""+ServerName;`

Comment: @MightyLampshade, It seems somehow webmethod does not like to accept single backslash (a kind of pre-validation may be) but `\\` passes validation which in next step becomes invalid because there are two backslashes.

Comment: @codingbiz, isn't @ only apply to first string? anyway my problem is in AJAX part that cannot send single backslash to server.

Comment: Have you tried just not adding the .\\ part of the name? So you only pass "sqlexpress"?

Comment: @MightyLampshade, As I mentioned in my post, yes as long as there is no backslash in text boxes it works. Actually, this problem only related to backslash. My example is a working sample to show how the problem happens. you can copy and paste it into visual studio and check yourself.

Comment: I don't really see any other way to get around it other than replacing the `\\` part of the string :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the character @ to make a string inescapable. So you cannot input escape characters in it (which is what your server think you are doing by putting a backslash).

Example:

```
string test = "This is a \r\n test";
Console.WriteLine(test);

OUTPUT:
This is a 
test

string test2 = @"This is a \r\n test";
Console.WriteLine(test2);

OUTPUT:
This is a \r\n test
```

I hope this can help you move forward :-).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however the first part is javascript and in javascript we don't have @ modifier to change string behavior.